# Test for inferring distribution of random variable

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose random variable $Z$ is known to come from one of two distributions: $X$ or $Y$. Given a set of observations $\{Z = z_i\}_{i=1}^{N} \;$, what would be the best statistical test(s) to use to infer the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: What do you know about the PDFs or CDFs of X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

**Choices.** Suppose $X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(5, 5),$ where the second parameter is the rate.
And suppose $Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(1, 1/\sqrt{5})$ where the second parameter is the standard deviation.
Both distributions have $\mu=1$ and 
$\sigma= 1/\sqrt{5}.$

I have 100 observations in a vector `z` sampled according to one of these two distributions and rounded to 2 decimal places. Which distribution?

**K-S test statistic.** Perhaps the best test is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#targetText=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov,sample%20K%E2%80%93S%20test), which essentially matches the
empirical CDF (ECDF) of the sample with the CDF of a distribution and rejects when the fit is bad.

**Data summary.** Summary statistics for `z`:

```
summary(z);  sd(z)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2800  0.6575  0.8950  0.9581  1.2125  2.0300 
[1] 0.3815934
```

You might suspect that the data are from the right-skewed gamma distribution because the sample mean is noticeably larger than the sample median, which sometimes indicates right-skewness.

**K-S Distances from R software.** The K-S test statistics `D` are shown below. (A few ties were induced by rounding; the K-S test as implemented in R, gives a warning message if any ties are present. I have deleted these warning messages).

The smallest statistic is for the gamma distribution.
So I choose the gamma distribution as the better fit. (The K-S test rejected neither model, but our criterion here is to use the smallest $D$ for identification.)

```
ks.test(z, "pgamma", 5, 5)$stat
         D 
0.06906961 

ks.test(z, "pnorm", 1, 1/sqrt(5))$stat
       D 
0.114528
```

**ECDF plots.** In each case it is the largest absolute vertical distance between the sample [ECDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) and the target CDF.
The ECDF plot of the sample (black dots) is the same
in each panel. The red curve at left is the CDF of
$\mathsf{Gamma}(5, 5)$ and the red curve at right
is the CDF for $\mathsf{Norm}(1, 1/\sqrt{5}).$
Visually, it is clear that the ECDF fits the gamma
CDF best.

[image]

---

*Note:*  Data were sampled using R statistical 
software as shown below. Using the `set.seed` statement, you will get exactly the same data used above.

```
set.seed(1023)
z = round(rgamma(100, 5, 5), 2)
```